# AWS boto3 key element does not match schema

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I created a table in dynamoDB and I am trying to do a read from python.

The error message is: "The provided key element does not match the schema"

The DB only has a primary partition key:
[image: aws snapshot]

This is my function:

```
def get_db_info(search_val='DEF123'):
    sts_client = boto3.client(
        'sts',
        region_name='us-east-1'
        )
    # Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role
    # ARN and a role session name.
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Server1_role",
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
    )
    
    credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
    
    dynamodb = boto3.resource(
        'dynamodb', 
        region_name='us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
    
    table = dynamodb.Table('defect-tracking')
    
    try:
        response = table.get_item(Key={"defect_id": search_val})
    except ClientError as e:
        return 'this is an error: ' + e.response['Error']['Message']
    else:
        return response['Item']
```

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with what you did. Are you *sure* the table has the schema you think it has? Can you please verify that search_val is indeed a string and nothing else (e.g., if it it's a number, it won't work. you can try `str(str_val)` to convert it into a string if it isn't)?

Comment: @NadavHar'El Thanks for your feedback. I am certain that search_val is a string (it is defined in the function).

Comment: @NadavHar'El search_val was defined in the function with a default value that was a string. You gave me the idea to hard code the value in the code for testing and it works. I'll put the details in an explanation below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a DynamoDB table called `defect-tracking` with a Primary Key of `defect_id` (String)
- Ran this shortened version of your code:

```py
import boto3

search_val = 'DEF123'

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('defect-tracking')

response = table.get_item(Key={"defect_id": search_val})

print(response)
```

**It worked fine for me.** It used IAM User credentials that have full access to DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did find the answer by moving search_val into the function instead of setting a default value like I had in the original post. I'll update the question with the correct syntax.

Comment: Found the answer: moved the value for search_val from being a default value in the function to hard coding it in the script for now. Must be something about how the function is being called.

Answer (score 1):

THis works. must have been an issue with how the function was being called that changed the default value for search_val:

```
def get_db_info():
    sts_client = boto3.client(
        'sts',
        region_name='us-east-1'
        )
    # Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role
    # ARN and a role session name.
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Server1_role",
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
    )
    
    credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
    
    dynamodb = boto3.resource(
        'dynamodb', 
        region_name='us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
    
    table = dynamodb.Table('defect-tracking')
    
    try:
        response = table.get_item(Key={"defect_id": 'DEF123'})
    except ClientError as e:
        return 'this is an error: ' + e.response['Error']['Message']
    else:
        return response['Item']
```